# Access Denied...?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
color 4
ping localhost 2.5 > nul
echo Welcome to the configuration menu.
echo Move AH1.exe and AH2.exe to your desktop.
echo This only works the first time
echo SO BE CAREFUL!
echo Would you like this to start on computer startup?
echo say "yes" or "no" below.
set /p option=Option:

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU no goto no
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU yes goto yes
:yes
echo Move AH1.bat and AH2.bat to desktop.
::Copies files to dekstop of current user *For Windows 7
xcopy "%systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop\AH1.bat" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
xcopy "%systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop\AH2.bat" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

echo Moved.
echo Press any key to close Anti Hacker Configuration.
pause > nul
exit
:no
echo No?The program will not take full effect then.
pause
exit
```

If you want to test,make 2 batch files on your desktop called AH1 and AH2
It says Access Denied....why??

Comment: By default only administrator accounts have write access to everything under `C:\ProgramData\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what you put into the `option` variable, it will *always* go to `:yes`.

I'm guessing you got mixed up with the `choice` command when you were making this because `errorlevel` doesn't contain the option you choose when you have the `set` command.

From the `set` documentation:

> %ERRORLEVEL% - expands to the current ERRORLEVEL value

So, you might want to change `if %errorlevel% equ no goto no` to `if %option% equ no goto no`.

Also, what happens if you don't put either `yes` nor `no`. You need to account for these things by perhaps having a `exit` command after the second `if` statement.